# Ordinal Predictors to Predict a Quantitative Value

Tags: regression

I was wondering if there is any technique/model that I can use to model a quantitative value using ordinal values. The data points I have consists of 4 ordinal variables (values are from 1-10). I also have the corresponding monetary values are based on the ordinal variables similar below

[image: Sample Data]

I want to make an equation to predict the Value column given the values from A, B, C, D. Is there any model/technique I can use to do so? Thanks